# Stream Object list as file from API

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible for a API endpoint to stream data from an IQueryable object list populated from entity framework, and linked to SQL database to create and return a csv file?

What I have so far is I loop through all the items in my list and create a temporary file. I then stream that file as the result of my GET API call.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/TmpData");

string tmpFileName = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/TmpData/{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.csv";

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(tmpFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        LookupItem liTmp = new();

        await fileStream.WriteAsync(nameof(liTmp.LookupItemId));
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(",");
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(nameof(liTmp.Code));
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(",");
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(nameof(liTmp.Label));
        await fileStream.WriteLineAsync();

        foreach (var li in items)
        {
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(li.LookupItemId.ToString());
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(",");
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(li.Code?.ToString());
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(",");
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(li.Label?.ToString());
            await fileStream.WriteLineAsync();
        }
    }
}

this.Response.StatusCode = 200;
this.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, $"attachment; filename=\"{ request.LookupTableType.ToString() } Data { DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh-MM-ss")}.csv\"");
this.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/octet-stream");
var inputStream = new FileStream(tmpFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var outputStream = this.Response.Body;
const int bufferSize = 1 << 10;
var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

while (true)
{
    var bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
await outputStream.FlushAsync();

System.IO.File.Delete(tmpFileName);

return new EmptyResult();
```

This works fine and I get a csv file back, but I was thinking is it possible to write the data straight to the output stream rather than creating a temp file? I don't want to load all the items in to memory as I would like to use this method on large data sets to allow users to download the table data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `EPPlus` package. below code I have tested, it works for me.

[image]

[image]

```
using dotnetcoreMVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace dotnetcoreMVC.Controllers
{
public class ForTestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult ExportData()
    {
        //TODO read data from db
        // Mock data
        List<TestModel> li = new List<TestModel>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TestModel m = new TestModel();
            m.id = 1+i;
            m.name = "test name"+ i;
            li.Add(m);
        }

        var data = li;

        if (data?.Any() != true)
        {
            return new ContentResult() { Content = "no data" };
        }

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        using (var ep = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var worksheet = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("export data for test"))
            {
                var x = 1;
                var y = 1;

                var columnTitles = new List<string>()
               {
               "id",
               "alias"
               };

                foreach (var columnTitle in columnTitles)
                {
                    var cell = worksheet.Cells[x, y++];
                    cell.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    cell.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    cell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
                    cell.Value = columnTitle;
                }

                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    x++;
                    y = 1;
                    var cell = worksheet.Cells[x, y++];
                    cell.Value = item.id;
                    cell = worksheet.Cells[x, y++];
                    cell.Value = item.name;
                }

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ep.SaveAs(stream);
                    return new FileContentResult(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                    {
                        FileDownloadName = Guid.NewGuid()+"test.csv"
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class TestModel { 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Would this need to load all of the data into memory before the stream is sent back 'ep.SaveAs(stream)' would save the file to memory before streaming the data back? What I think I was hoping for was to be able to say return this stream and it creates the stream row by row and returns it in chunks to the client. that way I don't need a temp file or to store all data in memory