# .NET Core Web API Return CSV in Reactjs

Tags: csv, asp.net-core

I am returning a csv file from an API using a csvformatter code shown below
API Call

```
[HttpGet("generatecsv/project/{projectId}/BookID/{bookId}")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
    public IActionResult Getcsv(string projectId, string bookId)
    {
        try
        {
            Models model = GetModel();
            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

CSV Formatter

```
public class CSVOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
    {
        public string ContentType { get; }
        public PDRDModels ViewModel { get; set; }

        public CSVOutputFormatter()
        {
            ContentType = "text/csv";
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType));
        }

        public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            var filePath = string.Format("./DataExport/PDRD-{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            ViewModel = context.Object as Models;

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteField("StackUp Information");
                csv.NextRecord();
                csv.NextRecord();
                WriteToCSV1(csv, ViewModel.Data1);
                foreach (var pdrdModel in ViewModel.PDRDModelList)
                {
                    csv.NextRecord();
                    csv.WriteField($"Physical Rules");
                    csv.NextRecord();
                    WriteToCSV2(ViewModel.Data2);
                }
            }
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Pdrd.csv");
            response.ContentType = "text/csv";

            await response.SendFileAsync(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The API returns the csv file as attachment when hit through the browser or Postman. But when hit through the UI code its just returning the csv response as a string not as an attachment.
Below is the UI Code for hitting the above end Point.

```
export const getExportedValues = async (projectId: string, bookId: string) => {
    if (projectId && bookId) {
        const finalUrl: string = `${getEnvConfig().projectsAPIUrl}/document/generatecsv/project/${projectId}/bookID/${bookId}`;
        let resp: any = await axios({ method: AxiosMethods.GET, url: finalUrl }).catch(err => errorFunction(err))
        if (!resp?.data?.error) {
            return resp?.data;
        }
    } else return {}

}
```

what am I missing in my reactjs Code to let this download as attachment instad of plain csv text

Comment: Try to return `FileContentResult` in your `Getcsv` method. After you click this link in your webapp, it will auto download it.  [You can refer my sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776061/stream-object-list-as-file-from-api/68815018#68815018)

Answer (score 0):

You code in axios should like below. Create `<a></a>` tag and click it, something like the link in my comment.

```
function invoke() {
    axios({
        url: '/ForTest/ExportData',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // important
    }).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    });
```

[image]

#### My test code

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@*<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>. 
    </p>
</div>*@
<div class="text-center">
    <a href="/ForTest/ExportData">download link</a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function invoke() {
        axios({
            url: '/ForTest/ExportData',
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob', // important
        }).then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv'); //or any other extension
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="text-center">
    <a onclick="invoke()">download_by_axios</a>
</div>
```